# Not visualizing signal in oscilloscope when a speaker is connected

Tags: arduino, audio, oscilloscope, speakers

Hope you can help me with this, because I really don't understand what is happening.

I have the following electronic circuit.

The Arduino is generating a tone and I am changing the volume with a digital potentiometer.

[image]

The problem I found is when I connect an oscilloscope to point A and GND I am able to visualize the signal 720mV  with the oscilloscope. However, when I connect an 8 ohm speaker to the output I have 50mV. I can hear it though,  but I would like to know what could be happening and how to solve it. Shouldn't I have the same voltage value at point A?

Comment: Slightly surprised that you can hear it; have you tried turning up the sensitivity on the scope? (smaller volts/div). The voltage will absolutely not be the same.

Comment: What scale did you use ? Was it AC, DC or Gnd selected?

Comment: When Speaker is not connected I can visualize the signal at 720 mV. When the speaker is connected I have nothing.   the diagram is not exhaustive, but all grounds are connected, I am also using SCL and SDA with Pull-ups to communicate with the DIGIPOT.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your drawing does not show a signal ground connection back to the Arduino?  Is there one?

Also, an 8 ohm speaker forms the shunt leg of an attenuator.  The series leg is the 100 ohm resistor plus the equivalent resistance of the digital pot.  The signal might be attenuated so much that it is below the quantizing level of the scope.  Can you increase the scope's vertical channel gain?

Starting with the signal level at the Arduino output pin, you can calculate the Thevenin equivalent voltage and impedance at the wiper of the digital pot.  This now is the signal source going into the 100 ohm resistor.  With Ohm's Law you can calculate the voltage across the 8 ohm speaker.

Note - the Thevenin equivalent values will change depending on the wiper position in the digital pot.  To see the full effect of this, run the calculations three times, with wiper positions of 10%, 50%, and 80%.

Comment: Yes, everything is connected to the same ground. Actually I have a voltage splitter when conecting the  Speaker, with the 100Ohms in serie and the 8 Ohms. Doing calculations, that's what I get. 50 mV using the 720mV I have with Open circuit.

Answer (score 0):

The output of your digital pot, or Arduino itself, is unable to drive the 8 ohm speaker. The speaker is acting like a near short to ground. You need some form of audio power amp after the volume control.